# SQL Server - Select column that contains query string and split values into anothers 'columns'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a select in a column that contains a query string like:

```
user_id=300&company_id=201503&status=WAITING OPERATION&count=1
```

I want to perform a select and break each value in a new column, something like:

```
user_id | company_id | status            | count
300     | 201503     | WAITING OPERATION | 1
```

How can i do it in SQL Server without use procs?

I've tried a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [xpto].[SplitGriswold]
(
   @List   NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delim1 NCHAR(1),
   @Delim2 NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  ( 
    SELECT 
      Val1 = PARSENAME(Value,2),
      Val2 = PARSENAME(Value,1)
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT REPLACE(Value, @Delim2, '&') FROM
      ( 
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim1, @List + @Delim1, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim1 + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim1)) = @Delim1
       ) AS y(Value)
     ) AS z(Value)
   );
GO
```

Execution:

```
 select QueryString 
 from User.Log 
 CROSS APPLY notifier.SplitGriswold(REPLACE(QueryString, ' ', N'ŏ'), N'ŏ', '&') AS t;
```

But it returns me only one column with all inside:

```
QueryString
user_id=300&company_id=201503&status=WAITING OPERATION&count=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean without built in functions?

Comment: I suppose you could do something using `locate` to find the occurrence of `user_id=` and then look for the next occurrence of `&`, do some funky work with substrings, it'd be very inefficient, but I guess it'd work(provided your string doesn't contain any funny content)

Comment: @scragar i'll look for it.

Comment: this might be useful: http://stevestedman.com/2012/04/using-a-cte-in-a-function-to-split-up-a-query-string/

Comment: @Tanner really useful but i need that 'user_id', 'company_id', 'status' and 'count' in same row for each row from User.Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do this many times before, and you're in luck! Since you only have 3 delimiters per string, and that number is fixed, you can use SQL Server's `PARSENAME` function to do it. That's far less ugly than the best alternative (using the XML parsing stuff). Try this (untested) query (replace TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME with the appropriate names):

```
SELECT
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'&','.'),1) AS 'User',
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'&','.'),2) AS 'Company_ID',
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'&','.'),3) AS 'Status',
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'&','.'),4) AS 'Count',
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

That'll get you the results in the form "user_id=300", which is far and away the hard part of what you want. I'll leave it to you to do the easy part (drop the stuff before the "=" sign).

NOTE: I can't remember if PARSENAME will freak out over the illegal name character (the "=" sign). If it does, simply nest another REPLACE in there to turn it into something else, like an underscore.

Comment: Happy to help! I should have pointed out the fine print of our contract beforehand, but you owe me your twenty-first born child. I'll wait.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use SQL SUBSTRING as part of your select statement. You would first need to build the first row, then use a UNION to return the second row.

Comment: an example would be useful as this doesn't really help the OP